# Sketch: export image at a resolution that does not add pixels

Tags: sketch-app

We're designing a website for CrummyPhotosCorp, who sends us a 150-pixel-tall image to put in an area that's 200 pixels high. We bring this photo into our Sketch comp and size it to fit the space. It doesn't look great, but what can we do?

Within Sketch, we make other adjustments to the photo, such as cropping the sides so you can't see a competitor's logo. Unfortunately, when we export the photo from Sketch, the saved file is 200 pixels tall—50 pixels more than the input photo.

The one advantage of low res imagery is that it saves bandwidth, and we don't want to lose this by adding fake pixels to the output file. Is there a way to force Sketch to never output at a higher resolution than the input photo?

Comment: I have no experience with Sketch, but it seems to me that it would be easier to edit images in an image editing software like Photoshop instead of directly in a design application. Anyway can't you just insert the image in a 150 px tall area instead of a 200 px tall area?

Comment: @Wolff Thanks! We’re already using Sketch to layout page comps for clients and developers, so it’s immensely beneficial to be able to export assets directly from Sketch as well. If we have to redo in Photoshop, we’re making the same photo adjustments twice. Also, the situation isn’t always as clean as the contrived example—particularly with 2x dpi images, sometimes I don’t even *know* whether Sketch has added pixels! I can check the original photo, but that also takes extra effort, and if the image has been cropped within Sketch, even then it’s not always clear.

Comment: I can't really see how using Photoshop would force you to do the same adjustments twice. Can't you just adjust, crop, scale etc. the images in Photoshop and then place them in Sketch? (I'm doing graphic design for print and that is what I do all the time - or rather the images are *placed* in InDesign/Illustrator as dynamic links and I can edit the images and update the links whenever it fits in the workflow.)

Comment: @Wolff - having checked the online documentation for Sketch app, I can find no references to placing dynamic linked raster images in Sketch. There is [a plugin](https://github.com/frankko/Place-Linked-Bitmap) however, but not being a Sketch user myself I can't check if this could be a solution to the OPs problem when exporting.